# How to split a string based on a character that follows another character?

Tags: typescript, string, ecmascript-6

I have a string in the following format:

```
"MyTeam/running#324242-BC2_asd213"
```

How can I get the part of the string that is before `-`. I.e. I need to get just `MyTeam/running#324242`. I would like to make sure that I split by the first occurrence of `-` after `#` because sometimes `-` can exist before # as well.

```
"MyTeam/walking-dead#324242"
```

In the above case I would like to get the string `MyTeam/walking-dead#567657`

My current solution:

```
.substring(0, vfi.lastIndexOf("-"));
```

But wondering if its possible to base it with "#" so that the solution is more accurate

Comment: The index of the first occurrence of `-` after `#` is `str.indexOf('-', str.indexOf('#'))`

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regex for this:

```
const regex = /^([^#]+[^-]*).*$/;

function extractAfterHashButBeforeDash(value: string) {
  return value.replace(regex, '$1');
}
```

- `^` means start of the string
- `[^#]+` will match 1 or more characters other than `#`
- `[^-]*` will match zero or more characters other than `-`
- `.*` will match zero or more characters
- `$` means end of the string

And the parenthesis capture the match you are interested so that you can use it for replace (using `$1`).